# Getting Java Scanner class error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Why I'm getting error in following Code? In the following code,
getMaximumWinning is a function, which returns a positive integer.

```
*Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)*
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int TC;

    Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);

    TC= s1.nextInt();

    int N,i;
    int win[]=new int[10000];
    String ques,ans;
    while(TC>0)
    {  N=s1.nextInt();
       ques=s1.next();
       ans=s1.next();
         for(i=0;i<=N;i++)
         {   
             win[i]=s1.nextInt();
         }

        System.out.println(getMaximumWinning(ques, ans, win, N));
        TC--;
    }


}
```

Comment: int win[]=new int[10000]; should be int[] win=new int[10000];

Comment: @vikasn91, I think both are same.

Comment: please post the full stacktrace, and also give us your input file

Comment: the stacktrace means that you donn't enter all required input values

Comment: I can't post that function, but ensures you that  it'll always return true;

Comment: Not the function, just the stacktrace and what you are giving at standard input

Comment: I don't know exactly about inputs, because it works fine on my machine but giving error on a online IDE.
Example input:
3
5
ABCDE
EBCDA
0 10 20 30 40 50

Answer (score 1):

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

indicates that you have no more elements presents in `Scanner`

before any `s1.nextInt();` you should use `s1.hasNextInt();` which returns boolean value depending on which you can decide what action to perform

```
if(s1.hasNextInt()){
    win[i]=s1.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Ok, i got you. But how is it possible. i.e no element in Scanner

Comment: @Ambika I think it is because using  s1.nextInt(); before and after  s1.next(); as next() return next token it can even be newline char or enter or space. when you read user input using next method, it does not read the newline at the end. Which is then read by the nextLine() try to debug your code or send complete SC

Comment: so i think, Exception is coming before giving any input to program?

Comment: Why its occurring, any idea.

Comment: did you pass any input to program before exception occur?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91976/discussion-between-kartik-agarwal-and-ambika).

Comment: still persists, what to do

Comment: @Ambika tell me your input data format i.e all input in one line or mixed

Comment: @Ambika try to replace next() via nextLine()